# How do I restore PenDriveLinux boot load menu after accidental overwrite?

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive, bootloader

I have a USB drive with Ubuntu created from pendrivelinux.com.  I've been running it off the USB drive to play with Linux on various machines without a problem.  I recently installed Ubuntu to a hard drive from the USB drive using the USB boot loader's menu option (versus the "install to hard drive" option found on the live-USB desktop).  Most everything installed correctly.  However the installer overwrote the boot loader on the USB drive and never installed it on the fixed disk such that I couldn't boot the machine without the USB drive.  I found [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/176050/ubuntu-server-installed-from-usb-putsgrub-on-theusb-drive-instead-of-the-hard/176088) that helped me to correct the fixed disk boot problem.  But I am still unable to boot to the USB installation.

I've been searching for a couple days but most of what comes up are articles describing how to set up a bootable USB with Linux on it.  I've poked around on the USB drive to see if there's some obvious boot loader config file but I can't find anything that seems like a candidate to change.  I have very limited knowledge of Linux so I don't know where to look or how to approach this problem.

I did look at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60966/cannot-boot-from-liveusb-created-with-pendrivelinux), but it wasn't of any help.

I could repave the bootable USB drive but since the original setup I have created a persistence disk, installed apps, and have various personal settings and such on the USB install.  I'd rather not do this when I imagine all I need to do is restore the pendrivelinux boot menu.  At this point, I'm backing up all the files on the USB drive to another machine and may attempt the repave with the hope that I can somehow restore only the changed/persisted part of the USB drive. (And unfortunately I've run out of usable USB drives on which I could do a fresh install of bootable ubuntu in order to compare that against the messed up one to see what could be restored.)

Answer (score 0):

I would try boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Look at the info on the Advanced Tab. Choose "place GRUB into" > sdb or whatever your USB thumbdrive is. Then Repair.